# How does this C code convert binary to decimal?

Tags: c

With respect to this code:

```
while(binary){
   digit = binary % 10;
   decimal += digit << base;
   base += 1;
   binary /= 10;
}
```

Can someone explain the working of this coding with an example?
How does it convert binary to decimal?

Comment: you can use `printf` to monitor the whole process.

Comment: Give `binary` a value and print out the result of each step, see if you can figure it out.

Comment: If I was a teacher I would start teaching programming by showing a hello world'ish (but a bit more complex) simple program in an acceptable free IDE and I would show the kids how to inspect the internal state of a program with a debugger. It would shorten the learning curve considerably in my opinion. Its surprising that so many beginners are playing around without a good debugger in the 21th century...

Comment: I use code blocks I know exactly how it goes .I just don't have knowledge of shift operator so I dont know its working .I know alternate logics though but I think its better to understand this logic then to ignore it.And Yes I also checked several websites and books but It doesn't have proper examples.And thanks for suggestion I will try using printf statment to know its working.

Answer (score 0):

use the following program, it will convert entered binary number to decimal number. refer following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    long b,dec=0,j=1,rem;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Binary number: ");
    scanf("%ld",&b);
    while(b!=0)
    {
        rem=b%10;
        ///////////////
        dec=dec+rem*j;
        ///////////////
        j=j*2;
        ///////////////
        b=b/10;
        ///////////////
    }
    printf("\nDecimal is %ld",dec);
    getch();
}
```